# Add item to @OneToMany FetchType.LAZY list without reading the list into memory?

Tags: hibernate

Given this:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "systemid")
private List<Thing> things = new ArrayList<>();
... other code ommitted for clarity ...
```

what is the safe, proper way to add a `Thing` to the list, without having to read the existing list into memory, and without compromising the integrity of the 2nd-level cache?

The naive solution is:

```
...getThings().add(newThing);
```

but reading the entire lazy list in `getThings()` is what I'd like to avoid.

Is it possible?